# The axis ticks don't show up on my d3 plot

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, axis

I'm a d3 newbie, I read data from csv file and was able to draw the bars and draw the axis, but the ticks don't show up on the axis, i searched many tutorials but nothing helped.
here is my code. Any help is appreciated.
I use d3 v5.
I read the data from csv file, append a svg to a div container, create rect for each data point as a bar, added the y-axis and the x-axis to the chart, I want the y-axis ticks to represent one column of the csv file, but they don't show up, I even tried fixed array in the domain of the y-axis (0-100) but didn't show up either, I tried to shift the y-axis to the left a little bit, but didn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<style>
div#container {
  width: 1050px;
  height: 600px;
  margin: auto;

}
svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

</style>
<body>
<div id="container" class="svg-container">
</div>
<script>

//------------------------SVG PREPARATION------------------------//
const margin = 80;

var adj = 0;
const svgwidth = 1050;
const svgheight = 600;
const width = 1050 - 2 * margin;
const height = 600 - 2 * margin;

// we are appending SVG first
var svg = d3.select("div#container").append("svg")
.attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
.style("padding", 5)
.style("margin", 5)
.classed("svg-content", true);

//-----------------------DATA PREPARATION------------------------//
var total=[];
var years = [];
var dataset = d3.csv("test.csv");
dataset.then(function(data) {
    data.map(function(d) {
            d.running_total = +d.running_total;
            total.push(d.running_total);
            years.push(d.year);
            return d;});
});

//---------------------------BAR CHART---------------------------//

dataset.then(function(data) {  
     svg.selectAll("div")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function (d, i) {
        for (i>0; i < data.length; i++) {
            return i * 21;
        }
    })
    .attr("y", function (d) {
        return height - (d.running_total*0.08);
    })
    .attr("width", 20)
    .attr("height", function (d) {
        return d.running_total*0.08;
    })
    .style("fill", "teal")
});

const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
.range([0, height])
.domain([d3.min(total), d3.max(total)]);

svg.append('g')
.attr("class", "y axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(50,0)")
.call(d3.axisLeft(yScale).ticks(20));

</script>
```

Comment: check the elements in the dev tools.  They might be there but outside the boundary of your svg.  you might need to translate further.

Comment: Thank you! I found the problem. I solved it my moving rendering the y-axis inside dataset block!